# @user_passes_test not working as expected - Django Python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have created a role based login in Django 3.1.2.

And i have used **@user_passes_test** decorator to check the role of user according to his/her role he can access the views, or we can say views will execute but it is not working as expected.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    GENDER = (
        (True, 'Male'),
        (False, 'Female'),
    )
    USER_TYPE = (
        ('Admin', 'Admin'),
        ('Designer', 'Designer'),
        ('Customer', 'Customer'),
    )
    user_id = models.AutoField("User ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField("User Avatar", null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.BooleanField("Gender", choices=GENDER, default=True)
    role = models.CharField("User Type", max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE, default='Customer')
```

Here in user models I have a field, with help of that I can specify user role and default is Customer.

**views.py**

```
# view to check whether a user is Designer or Admin
def check_role_admin_or_designer(user):
    if user.is_authenticated and (user.role == 'Admin' or user.role == 'Designer'):
        print(user.role)
        return True


# view to check whether a user is Admin
def check_role_admin(user):
    if user.is_authenticated and (user.role == 'Admin' or user.is_superuser):
        return True
    else:
        return HttpResponse("You are not Authorized to access this page")

# my login view
def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.role == 'Customer':
        return redirect('user-home')
    if request.user.is_authenticated and (
            request.user.role == 'Admin' or request.user.role == 'Designer' or request.user.is_superuser):
        return redirect('admin-home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:

                login(request, user)
                return redirect('admin-home')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Username or Password is incorrect')
                return redirect('admin-login')

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'admin1/login.html', context)


# view that I want to allow if and only if the user role is ADMIN
@login_required(login_url="admin-login")
@user_passes_test(check_role_admin)
def addUser(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/admin1/addUser')

    addUser_show = User.objects.all()
    # start paginator logic
    paginator = Paginator(addUser_show, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        addUser_show = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        addUser_show = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        addUser_show = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    # end paginator logic
    return render(request, 'admin1/addUser.html',
                  {'addUser_show': addUser_show, "form": form})


# View I want to allow access whether the users role is ADMIN or DESIGNER
@login_required(login_url="admin-login")
@user_passes_test(check_role_admin_or_designer)
def templateImage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        temp_img = request.FILES['temp_img']
        templateImage_update = ImageTemplate(temp_img=temp_img)
        templateImage_update.save()
        return redirect('/admin1/templateImage')
    else:
        templateImage_show = ImageTemplate.objects.all()
        # start paginator logic
        paginator = Paginator(templateImage_show, 3)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            templateImage_show = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            templateImage_show = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            templateImage_show = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        # end paginator logic
        return render(request, 'admin1/templateImage.html', {'templateImage_show': templateImage_show})
```

- The main problem which I am facing is whether I login as **ADMIN** or **Designer** it allows everyone to access all the pages or we can say allow access to execute all the views.
- I want to put restrictions on the basis of roles, I don't want to use Django's option **(is_superuser, is_staff, Is_active)**

The Code is working well and there isn't any error but its not giving the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I don't know I am doing this is correct way or not, but the solution I tried is working for me.
- I have just added else statement in both the functions **check_role_admin_or_designer**, **check_role_admin**, which checks the role of user.

**views.py**

```
def check_role_admin_or_designer(user):
    if user.is_authenticated and (user.role == 'Admin' or user.role == 'Designer'):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def check_role_admin(user):
    if user.is_authenticated and (user.role == 'Admin' or user.is_superuser):
        return True
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```